# How to install requests module for Python 3.2 by using pip install?

Tags: 12.04, python

I have Ubuntu 12.04 with Python 2.7 and 3.2
Following [this page](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/#install) I installed requests module.

```
$ sudo pip install requests
```

However, it only works for Python 2 but not Python 3:

```
$ python
Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:11:55) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named requests
>>>
```

How should I install the requests module so it can work for both my Python versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Answered by OP:*

> I figured it out by following various answers from
>   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3).
>   The answer is I have to have pip-3.2 installed first. I am not sure
>   all steps are necessary though:
>
> ```
> $ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
> $ sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
> $ sudo python3 -m easy_install pip
> ...
> Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
> Installing pip-3.2 script to /usr/local/bin
> .. Now I get pip-3.2:
>
> $ sudo pip-3.2 install requests
> ```